# Trying to optimize my if-statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm currently in the progress of creating my first ever game in C++ and I've got an if-statement looking something like this, it's pretty long and inconvinient, and I really think there's a shorter and more optimal way of doing this and that's what I need help.

EDIT: Data type is an integral, sorry for any inconvinience this brought to the question. I got the answer though as simple as it was! Happy holidays!

```
if (rectangle == 1 ||
    rectangle == 2 ||
    rectangle == 3 ||
    rectangle == 4 ||
    rectang... and so on
```

Comment: is `rectangle` integral?

Comment: Not sure why all the downvotes.  It seems like a reasonable, if basic question.

Comment: If range checking with less than/greater than comparison is not practical, then check out [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)

Comment: This may very well be the XY problem. You have a real problem to solve, you attempt a solution and ask about the point in your solution where you get stuck, rather than asking about the overall problem. For this particular question the answer would be ranges, but there might be better solutions to the original problem than having that check

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
if(rectangle >= 1 && rectangle <= maxRectangle)
    doSomething();
```

Comment: Can't believe I did not think of this myself! Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: Not a problem... Happy to help! Happy holidays!

Comment: Technically this answer can't be assumed to be correct, as we don't know if `rectangle` is of integral type.

Comment: @JBentley Given that OP accepted it and exact comparisons with floating point numbers are almost always incorrect, I'd say you are nitpicking.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry - it's of the data type integral. Will add it to the question.

Comment: @delnan When I was typing that, the OP hadn't submitted his comment yet. Also, there are more types in C++ than just integral and floating point. If anything, I'd assume a class named `Rectangle` to be a user defined type.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (rectangle >= 1 && rectangle <= n)
```

should be the easiest thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information to properly understand your problem.

But if you're testing to see it's not 0

```
if(rectange)
//logic
```

If you're testing to see that it's between some range

```
//range1-100
if(rectange && rectange < 101)
```

If you're testing a specific set of numbers

```
int acceptableNumbers[100];
//assume some numbers are filled into this array

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
     if(rectange == acceptableNumbers[i])
          //Logic
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the first post. Thank you for this either way!

Comment: Hmm maybe some type of std::set for the last one for fast lookup.

Comment: @drescherjim locality>O notation usually.  And the `unordered_set` would be faster: `set` only when you care about order.